# How to update a Plot with drawRect with UIView subclassing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Ok, I can create a plot.  But if I want the plot to be given data points one at a time at every 1 second interval, I don't know how to get it to work other than redrawing the plot each time.
What methodology do I need to apply to add more data points to the plot subclassing UIView?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.
}

- (void)addSample: ??{
    ???
}
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your plot uses a data set that’s in a mutable collection, like an NSMutableArray, and that your `-drawRect:` pulls from that collection, then your `-addSample:` method just needs to add its data points to that collection and then call the view’s `-setNeedsDisplay`. Your `-drawRect:` will then get called at the next iteration through the run loop, thereby redrawing the graph.

Comment: I just want to add another point to the plot, not redraw the entire plot. ??

Comment: If you’re only doing it every second or so, redrawing the whole thing will have negligible performance impact. Usually a graph like that needs to be redrawn repeatedly as its data set grows, whether to adjust the scale or to remove older data points—is there some reason that’s not a concern here?

Comment: I will be setting plot limits right at the beginning.  I do not want the plot resizing.  There eventually will be up to 10,000 points on the plot.